# Bootstrap 3 make-clumn mixins issue: disabled gutters

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

When I use few mixins make-*-column for a class(to make it responsive), a gutter(padding-left:15px by default) disappeared. If use only one mixin, all work well.

Example:

```
contacts_info{
    @include make-xs-column(12);
    @include make-sm-column-offset(1);
    @include make-sm-column(10);
    @include make-md-column-offset(3);
    @include make-md-column(6);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Output css(with 320px display width):

```
.contacts_info {
color: #fff;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;}
```

If I use only one mixin, I get correct css

```
.contacts_info {
color: #fff;
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;}
```

Ofcourse I can fixed it manually by adding padding-left in my scss, but I want something clever way